# Change the scheduled time on an akka task

Tags: playframework, akka

Hi I have an akka actor:

```
public class StatusActor  extends UntypedActor {
public static ActorRef instance = Akka.system().actorOf(
        new Props(StatusActor.class));

public void onReceive(Object message) {
    Logger.info("Message received");
}
```

}

And I create a schedule for it ever 5 minutes:

```
Akka.system().scheduler().schedule(
        Duration.create(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
        Duration.create(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES), StatusActor.instance, null);
```

The problem I have is I want to change this time dynamically? Is there any way I can do this? I cannot find any methods to stop it. So then I can just start it again.

The only hack way I have thought of is at the end of the onReceive have it call the akka schedule to start again, and change all the values to run once, and have a static variable in the StatusActor for the frequency.

If anyone could tell me how to stop an actor/get access to it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd look at the return value of schedule, either in your IDE or in the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0.2/#akka.actor.Scheduler) you'd see that it returns a Cancellable, so you can cancel the previous and schedule a new one.

Hope that helps!

Cheers,
√

Comment: Thanks this should do the trick. Now i need to put it somewhere nice as I'm running the schedule on startup so I wont have access to this class from other classes.

Answer (score 1):

Several steps you need to do:

1 You need to have a global key-value variable. Here I use ConcurrentHashMap, because normal HashMap is not safe in multi-threaded environment.

```
var schedulerIDs = new ConcurrentHashMap[String, Cancellable]().asScala
```

2 Every time you create a scheduler, you need to store it to key-value variable. You need to design your key, here I use the scheduler's create time and the user who creates this scheduler as key (Just because it is unique and it is easy for me to restore it back.). And its value is its cancelable variable. (Remember you can't read its content, because it is just cancelable type. )

```
val schedulerID = system.scheduler.schedule(initialDelay, interval, myActor, subMessage)

val schedulerKey = startTime + userName
val filterOption = schedulerIDs.get(schedulerKey)
filterOption match {
  case None =>
    schedulerIDs += schedulerKey -> schedulerID
  case _ =>
}
```

3 When you want to modify one scheduler, you need to fetch its info from key-value variable to get its cancelable variable. And then using this cancelable variable to cancel this scheduler first and remove this scheduler from this key-value variable.

```
def removeScheduler(createTime: String, userName: String) {
  val schedulerKey = createTime + userName
  val filterOption = schedulerIDs.get(schedulerKey)
  filterOption match {
    case None =>
    case Some(value) =>
      value.cancel()
      schedulerIDs.remove(schedulerKey)
  }
}
```

4 Final step is to create a new scheduler going to step2 and going back to Step1 to store it.

This solution uses global variable to store scheduler info. The benefit of it is fast, but the disadvantage is that when the server is down, all of these info would be gone. Because global variable will be gone when the server is down.

So normally I will store schedulers info into DB in Step1 together to restore everything back according to its scheduler info(like, init time, interval, etc). Exactly like create new schedulers. But users or front-end will not notice it.